# jQuery .post or .get pass dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The common way to send some request to server is

```
$.get('link/to/send', {
   param1: "value1",
   param2: "value2"
}, function(result) {
   // ... etc
});
```

Now if I want to send dynamic parameter names, can jQuery support that? (i.e. I need to write some generic code so that I can specify parameter names at runtime)

Comment: look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation

Comment: Can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 4):

This is not jQuery dependent, it's only vanilla JavaScript.

You should do this:

```
var objToSend = {};
objToSend["param1"] = "value1";
objToSend["param2"] = "value2";

$.get('link/to/send', objToSend, function(result) {
    // ... etc
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done using bracket notation. You can access object properties using square bracket (`[]`) just like you would access the values of an array.

In your case, the code could look like this:

```
//Name of the parameters
var str1 = "param1";
var str2 = "param2";

//Create an empty object
var obj = {};

//Set the values of the parameters.
obj[str1] = "value1";
obj[str2] = "value2";

//Send the GET request.
$.get('link/to/send', obj, function(result) {
   // ... etc
});
```

This code should be synonymous with the code in your question. It sends one parameter named `param1` with value `value1`, and one named `param2` with value `value2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. You just create your dynamic data and call the function with your dynamic data as argument.

```
function sendRequest(data)
{
   $.get('link/to/send',data, function(result) { /* code here*/ });
}
```